# XCUIElement unique identifier

Tags: xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

In XCUITests, is there an unique way to identify a given XCUIElement that persists across queries?

I can't use labels because sometimes elements can come with identical labels.

Hash/hashvalue works within a given query, but it is refreshed after consecutive queries.

As always, I can't find documentation on this subject :(

Answer (score 2):

You can uniquely identify `XCUIElement`s by setting an `accessibilityIdentifier` on the `UIView` object they represent.

```
// app code
let button = UIButton()
button.accessibilityIdentifier = "myButton"

// test code
let app = XCUIApplication()
let button = app.buttons["myButton"]
button.tap()
```

Accessibility identifiers are used solely for the purpose of UI testing. They are not localised and it is your responsibility to set the accessibility identifier to something that is as unique as you require. The accessibility identifier will persist for the lifetime of the view, unless your code explicitly changes it.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I'm aware of accessibilityIdentifiers, but in this case all elements already have the same (they are repeating elements of the same class). And even if it wasn't the case, they aren't really unique

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done it is to add the indexPath.row to the end of a String and set that as the AccessibilityIdentifier.

```
self.accessibilityIdentifier = "ProfileTableViewCell-\(indexPath.row)"
self.detailLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = "ProfileTableViewCell-DetailLabel-\(indexPath.row)
```

I even add the row value to the internal cell elements.